# async + axios or just axios, that's the question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

is there a difference between

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  async function fetchData(){
    await axios
      .get(path, config)
      .then(resp=>console.log(resp))
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  }
  fetchData();
},[])
```

&

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  axios
    .get(path, config)
    .then(resp=>console.log(resp))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
},[])
```

is there one that is more recommended or one that is more depreciated than the other one?

in terms of results both give the same, the "async" is newer, but other than that is there something?

thanks,

Comment: Well that really depends on what you are doing. axios itself returns an async function. wrapping an async function iside another async function with no other functionality just seems pointless.

Comment: For the first example: why would you _ever_ use this? You're making a function make a function with the code you need to run, then you run it. So.... just run that code instead of nesting it in a throw-away function. As for the second example: why are you using curly braces? No need for them at all there. But finally: if you have `await`, don't also use `then` for the same calls. `const resp = await axios.get(...);`, not `await axios.get(...).then(resp => ...)`.

Comment: same result different way to do bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is typically used with conjunction with await. Usually, if you aren't going to declare await in the function, there's no need to use async. However, `async` makes writing asynchronous code cleaner. In the first example

```
useEffect(()=>{
  async function fetchData(){
    await axios
      .get(path, config)
      .then(resp=>console.log(resp))
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  }
  fetchData();
},[])
```

the `.then` and `.catch` clauses are redundant since, you can easily re-write this in a cleaner fashion:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
      async function fetchData(){
       try{
        const result = await axios.get(path, config)
        console.log(result)
       }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
       }
      }
      fetchData();
    },[])
```

This minimizes the chance of entering "callback hell" because asynchronous functions can be written in a synchronous way, which depending on your preference, is more intuitive and allows you to return a result directly from a declared function.

However, `.then` and `.catch` clauses do come in handy when you don't need a result from the declared function, and can sometimes be faster to write. For most developers it comes down to personal preference, although if you develop in cloud infrastructure, and use `AWS Lambda` functions, `async/await` becomes more essential given the event-driven, and functional nature of cloud development, where you can't really persist state easily.

Comment: Hi thanks for your message, in terms of effectiveness both are working the same all is just dev preferences unless for cloud base work where async/await is essential, is that what you mean?

Comment: That's exactly it. The reason they're essential in the cloud is because most cloud functions are asynchronous but they usually need to return a value. Therefore, `async/await` is the only way to do this as a `.then` clause would not return a result, as the timing would be missed. Therefore, whenever you want a declared async function to return a result, you use `async/await`. If not, its really up to preference. In recent times, `async/await` has become faster on browsers though, due to V8 engine improvements, but for all intents and purposes, its really negligible.

Comment: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async you can read about the improvements here :) !

Answer (score 0):

you're actually mixing up to different syntaxes.

The first one is the async/await method of getting requests which is more like this:

```
try{
const response = await axios.get(request)
return response
}
catch(err){
return err
}
```

The second one using then and catch is like this:

```
const response = axios.get(request).then(res=>return res).catch(err=>return err);
```

Now both of these are different ways of doing the same exact thing, however, async/await is newer and a cleaner syntax which improves code readability. So it is usually more preferred to use the async/await syntax

I hope my answer mixed with @ArkyAsmals answer helps you !

Comment: Hi, 

I think you misunderstand my question, I am not mixing up things.
`const response = axios.get(resquest).then(res=>res).catch(err=>err)`
is same as 
`axios.get(request).then(res=>setData(res)).catch(err=>setError(err))`
just a different way but the same result.

Comment: Please look at my answer again, I never said that these 2 are different. I am merely saying that you are mixing up the await with .then

Comment: Sorry, last paragraph is clearer than the beginning one, xD